# Applying for a Schengen visa from Greek embassy with an expired resident visa in Israel?

Tags: legal, schengen, israel, filipino-citizens

I'm Philippines passport holder and currently living in Israel. A few months ago my resident permit expired and I'm ready to go back home for good. My question is - can I apply for a Schengen visa in Greece even for just 2 weeks because I want to travel before going back to the Philippines?

Comment: To clarify - you want to apply for it while you are in Greece, or you want to go to Greece?

Comment: i want to go in greece. im working in israel for a quite sometime and im philippines holder passport. could it be possible to get schegen visa from greece embassy although my resident visa here in israel has been expired? i want only a 2weeks travel in greece then afterwards i will go back home in philippines for good

Answer (score 4):

You will need a valid resident/work visa in the host country in order to apply for a Schengen Visa (in a foreign country).

I could not find a specific page for your case (Greek Embassy in Israel) but going quickly through few other Greek Embassies in other countries (for example, [the Greek embassy in the U.S website](http://www.mfa.gr/usa/en/services/services-for-non-greeks/visa-section.html)) shows that a Valid resident visa is required, hence I am sure all other Greek embassies will ask for the same.